# $Pr<W$ and $Pr>D$ - interpretation of statistic tests results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normality-assumption, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have found the following test results:

[image: Statistic tests results]

Source: [Link](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~tqin/system101/method/QQplot_sas.htm)

Could you tell me what does it mean and how to interpret the following quantities: $Pr<W$, $Pr>D$, $Pr>W-Sq$ and $Pr>A-Sq$?

For example I understand that $W$ is the value of statistic computed in Shapiro-Wilk test, however we cannot see here the critical value of statistic as well as we do not have information what is the null hypothesis of particular tests. Therefore, to assess whether we reject null hypothesis or not we have to rely on the second part of the table, which is not clear for me...

$Pr<W$ looks like p-value, but what about $Pr>D$ and others?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The others also are p-values, as indicated by the heading over the rightmost column.  What, then, remains to be clarified?

Comment: Why once we have $<$ whearas in the other cases $>$?

Comment: It depends on the test: for some, a small value of the statistic is significant and for others, a large value is. Consulting documentation on the individual tests is always a good idea so that you know what you're doing when you act on its result.

Comment: But at the end of day we only have to look at the last number? If it is enough small we reject null hypothesis, regardless whether we have $<$ or $>$ sign?

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests.